# How to set up correctly a git_clone?

Tags: c++, git, git-clone, libgit2

I'm doing a C++ program that should clone several repositories using libgit2.
The problem is that when I clone a repository, it clone the whole content into the path but it doesn't create a sub-file unlike when I do the same command with git bash where it clone into a subfile.

```
git_libgit2_init();
git_repository *repo = NULL;


    error = git_clone(&repo, url, path, NULL);

    git_repository_free(repo);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the repository *Foo*.

When you writes in *bash*:

```
$ git clone url
```

Using your *libgit2* example it is quite equivalent to:

```
error = git_clone(&repo, url, "./Foo", NULL);
```

Actually it means that the [`git_clone()`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/clone/git_clone)'s third parameter is not the path to the directory where to clone the repository, but it is the path to the local repository itself (so you have to provide the repository name too, of course you can change it).

Knowing this, if I use your example again and write the following:

```
error = git_clone(&repo, url ,"/path_to_somewhere/Bar", NULL);
```

It will be equivalent as if I had written in *bash*:

```
$ git clone url /path_to_somewhere/Bar
```

The remote *Foo* repository will be renamed as *Bar* (only in my local repository of course).

---

Therefore, to give you a concrete answer :) You just have to append the repository name to the destination path and it will be created as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

what's the error messages. `git_clone` do something like this:

```
git_libgit2_init();
git_repository *repo = NULL;
git_clone_options clone_options;//the struct is clone credential.and other info.
error = git_clone(&repo, url, path, &clone_options);

git_repository_free(repo);
git_libgit2_shutdown();
```